# unbounded array in visual c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

By accident, it appears I am creating an unbounded array, which I didn't think was possible in c#.  I am not getting any errors, and the code works, but I see no reference to the array declaration I used in online documentation.  I tried using this method in other situations and I get an error every time.  Why does this work?

```
Array arrLines;

arrLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strTargetFilePath2);
foreach (string strLine2 in arrLines)
{
eventLog1.WriteEntry(strLine2);
}
```

Comment: It's not unbounded. Try something like `arrLines[arrLines.Length] = "foo"` after your `ReadAllLines` and you'll quickly see that it is bounded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Array arrLines;` does not actually create an array.  It just sets up a variable that you can assign an array to.

You don't have to set up a length when you declare `arrLines` because it is a reference type, which means that it holds an address to the hypothetical array content instead of the array content itself.

`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(strTargetFilePath2);` 
is what creates the array, and yes, that array does have a specific length.

Comment: so it creates a finite array based on the number of lines it read?

Comment: @XiVix yes, it does.